# SBT-like Continuous Compilation for g++/make

Tags: compilation, g++, makefile, sbt

SBT allows for continuous compilation of a project's source code using `~ compile`. It watches the source-file directory and recompiles the project whenever a file is modified. That way, you don't need to wait to recompile your project after making changes to the source code.

Does anyone know of any equivalent for doing this using GNU c++ / make? This continuous compilation feature would be very useful for the C++ projects that I'm working on. I am using g++ 4.7.2 and GNU make 3.81 .